# How to generate unique colored images in python

Tags: python

Hello I’m a beginner in programming and I have been trying to generate just unique color square images with their RGB code written on them. I have this so far but have no idea on where to go from here. Any help would be very appreciated.

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
img = Image.new('RGB', (100, 30), color = (73, 109, 137))
d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
d.text((10,10), "Rgb value", fill=(255,255,0))
img.save('pil_text.png')
```

Comment: Please read [tour] and [ask]. What is the problem with your code?

Comment: what do you mean by _unique colour_?

Comment: Matiiss sorry for not providing enough information I mean unique like non-repeating/different colors for every image

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will get you started on generating the unique color images but for understanding it, you need to get yourself familiar with `python` [`lists & tuples`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types), [`f-strings`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) and [`for loop`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements).

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
colors = [(73, 109, 137), (99, 99, 99)]
for color in colors:
    img = Image.new('RGB', (100, 30), color=color)
    d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

    d.text((10,10), f"{color}", fill=(255,255,0))

    img.save(f'RGB_{color}.png')
```